# Est-il possible de quantifier un « instant » ?

Tags: sens

Lorsque l'on parle de secondes, de minutes, on se rend tout de suite compte du temps que cela va prendre puisque ce sont des unités temporelles définies. Ce qui n'est selon moi pas le cas pour un « instant ».

On entend souvent des phrases comme celles-ci :

> Un instant s'il vous plait.

ou

> Merci d'attendre quelques instants.

Mais à quoi peut correspondre un « instant » ou « quelques instants » ?

Est-il possible de quantifier un « instant » ?

Edit: si selon vous il n'est pas possible de quantifier un « instant », peut être qu'une quantification relative par rapport à une autre mesure de temps peut être intéressante.

Comment: La flamme d'une bougie dans la profondeur de l'éternité...

Comment: C'est le temps que met le fût du canon pour refroidir après le tir. (Fernand Raynaud)

Comment: La personne ayant voté à la baisse la question pourrait-elle expliquer pourquoi ?

Comment: [Question récurante...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=who+voted+down) Désolé.

Comment: @F.Hauri Ah non ! Ça c'est « un certain temps » ;)

Comment: **Un instant douloureux** où l'émotion était particulièrement palpable. https://www.lindependant.fr/2012/06/21/emouvante-commemoration,147441.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne pense pas qu'il soit possible de quantifier ce qu'est un instant.

*Instant* a deux définitions:

1. Un moment précis
2. Une durée de temps très brève

De ceci on peut conclure qu'un instant représente une durée qui correspond à un moment précis et qui doit être très bref, mais en pratique ceci peut varier de 30 secondes à une demie heure.

Comment: Je pense qu'un *instant* est *plus court* qu'un *moment*: Instant partage sa racine avec Instantané, tandis qu'un *bon moment* est appelé à durer.

Comment: @drat: Merci pour cette bonne réponse.

Answer (score 4):

## Demande de quantification

La réponse scientifique serait de dire qu'un instant dure **5.39121 × 10<sup>-44</sup> secondes** ([temps de Planck](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_de_Planck)).

C'est à dire que l'on considère qu'un instant est **la plus petite mesure temporelle possible**. Le terme "possible" est **à nuancer** suivant l'état actuel des connaissances scientifiques.

Vu l'ordre de grandeur extrêmement faible (et encore le mot est extrêmement faible lui aussi), il n'a **aucun sens à l'échelle humaine**.

---

## Autres unités de mesures

Pour rebondir sur ton *édit*, je me demande si un **instant** ne serait pas justement une autre unité de mesure du temps, universellement admise bien que non mesurable, ce qui est plutôt paradoxal.

C'est d'ailleurs la seule autre unité de temps que j'ai trouvée qui ne soit pas basée sur la seconde (si on considère bien sûr que les saisons, les lunes, etc. sont elles aussi basées sur la seconde ; chose discutable je l'accorde).

Comment: Merci pour la réponse scientifique que j'apprécie. Cependant, lorsqu'on parle d'attendre un instant, généralement on attend un peu plus que `5.39121 x 10^-44` secondes.

Comment: C'était pour répondre à ta demande de quantification, mais effectivement n'a aucun sens pour un cerveau humain. Et pour rebondir sur ton édit, je me demande si un "instant" ne serait pas justement un autre unité de mesure du temps universellement admise, bien que non mesurable (c'est paradoxal).

Comment: +1: je suis assez d'accord avec ton dernier paragraphe.

Answer (score 1):

Le petit Robert nous indique : *Durée très courte que la conscience saisit comme un tout* ou encore *le moment présent*.

Dans le cadre d'une réponse à une demande précise, comme le suggère la question, si l'on se met à la place de celle ou de celui qui répond *un instant*, l'instant devient une notion subjective (notion de conscience) qui intègre le temps à venir dans l'*ici et maintenant* (le moment présent) pour définir le moment le plus proche où « je pourrai focaliser mon attention sur vous ».

« Vous savez que l'on ne peut (bien) faire qu'une chose à fois, vous me voyez occupé à réaliser une action, je vous ai entendu, dès que mon action (aussi *courte* que possible) sera terminée toute mon attention sera disponible pour vous. » 
Voilà ce que cet *un instant* contient, contenu difficilement exprimable en langage mathématique.

L’instant est lié à la conscience c’est à dire à l’humain et non au mental c’est à dire à l’objet chronomètre qui ne sait prévoir que le futur d'un processus scientifique ; sa ‘conscience’ du *tout* se définit en secondes arithmétiques, en période circadienne, annuelle, astronomique on infinitésimale.

C'est une *intuition* qui estime la durée de la réalisation de l'action en cours lorsque l'on a les mains occupées ou que l'on est dans une situation d'échange avec son environnement.

En général, l'évaluation intuitive de celle ou celui regarde n'est pas la même quant à la durée d'attente escomptée, d'où naissance de conflit possible sur cet *instant* non quantifiable ..

> L’instant est la conscience de la durée dans le temps,
>   
>  L’instant est un regard porté sur la durée,

il n’est en aucun cas objet de mesure objective.

*L’instant présent* est le point zéro qui demeure sans cesse à zéro : soit il est présent, soit il n’est plus.

Comment: Serait-il possible de clarifier la réponse car elle difficile à comprendre ?

Comment: Objectivement l'instant peut être numérisé en une fraction de seconde comme le définit 'Fractaliste' ... et la réponse est courte. Cependant subjectivement, il n'en est rien : la durée de l'instant dépend uniquement de l'humain qui formule la réponse et des circonstances dans lesquelles il se trouve ... et en prenant la place de celui qui formule *un instant* dans la question j'ai (peut-être vainement) essayé de *qualifier* l'instant par rapport à celui (ou celle) qui prononce ce mot, et laissé à celui qui l'écoute la possibilité de le *quantifier* selon son intuition.

Comment: Merci pour la précision.

Answer (score 1):

D'après le physicien Marc Lachièze-Rey, l'instant est nul (c'est comme le point qui n'a aucune dimension en géométrie). On ne peut additionner des instants pour constituer une durée, même très courte.

Une horloge ne peut mesurer que des durées. Le temps de Planck est la plus petite mesure que l'on pourrait effectuer ; ce n'est pas la grandeur d'un l'instant mais une durée.
Actuellement, la plus petite durée mesurée est de 2,47.10-21 s, durée de la traversée d'une molécule H2 par un photon.

À lire : *Le temps, instant et durée*, de Pierre Buser et Claude Debru, éd. Odile Jacob 2011.

Comment: On pourrait arguer que du point de vue du photon, la traversée de l'**univers** s'effectue en un instant...

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de définition quantifié d'*1* instant, lorsqu'un instant est une durée, il représente une durée brève. Cela dépend du contexte, la disparition d'une étoile en 10 ans ou le temps pour une allumette de s'emflammer

par rapport à la deuxième partie de la réponse de @Fractaliste, d'autres ce sont déjà intéréssé (sur le ton  humoristiques) à ces "unités" de mesures, il y en beaucoup. exemple et source:

> L'instant
>
> Unité strictement équivalente au bout de temps et à l'éternité, mais
>   qui accorde à l'intervalle mesuré un préjugé de décontraction,
>   d'aisance et de légèreté.
>
> EXEMPLE : Je me remets au boulot dans un instant, le temps de finir
>   mon verre.

source: [Système d'unité pifométrique](http://pifometrie.indriya.org/chapitre4_5.php)

Answer (score 0):

Jakob bon uexkull signale dans son ouvrage Monde animal et monde humain que les "instants sont les plus petits contenants temporels... Ils sont l expression de sentirs élémentaires indivisibles...des signaux instantanés" qu il évalue à un 18 ème de seconde